# How do I update at attribute on multiple models in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I would like to perform this action with the click of a link.

```
def index    
   @books = Book.all
end

def update_read_books
  @books.each do |book|
    book.update_attribute(:read, true)
  end
end
```

How can I update mark all books as read?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails has an `update_all` method. [See link](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_all/class).

```
def mark_as_read
  Book.update_all(read: true)
  redirect_to books_path
end
```

Setup up route to give you `/books/mark_as_read`

```
resources :books do
  get :mark_as_read, on: :collection
end
```

Then in your view:

```
= link_to "Mark all as Read", mark_as_read_books_path
```

If you really want to be Restful, you can make your route a put/patch method. Don't forget to change your link to the method you choose.

If you want this to be an Ajax request, you can add a `remote: true` to the link:

```
= link_to "Mark all as Read", mark_as_read_books_path, remote: true
```

That will make it async. Then you need to handle that response in the controller.

```
def mark_as_read
  Book.update_all(read: true)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to books_path }
    format.js
  end
end
```

... and add a template inside `/views/books/update_all.js.erb` and add some jQuery to remove the notification. For example:

```
$('#notification_count').hide();
```

Comment: the link_to block for me is basically a dropdown menu (using bootstrap). With this method, it will lead me to the mark_as_read_books_path but I don't want it to. I just simply want the click to update all read booleans to true

Comment: And what's the problem with that? That's exactly what this solution does. You redirect back to `index` after you have updated all the books. Don't try to shoehorn an update action into your index method. It's not a good idea. Just update the books then redirect back, or to index, or wherever you want.

Comment: The dropdown will display a list of the books you've read. It's a different type of app & it's hard to explain but look at stackoverflow's notification dropdown. You see how clicking on it resets the notification count back to 0?

Comment: Jon, the index action is for listing things. If you really want to perform an update operation, you need to add a hook to you link. Add a  param like `link_to "foo", books_path(update_all: true)` - then in the index action check if the param is present: `if params[:update_all].present? # do stuff and redirect`... but ask yourself, why do that instead of moving the update all into its own action?

Comment: Jon, that's done using JavaScript. SO either polls or queries the server to find any unread notifications. It then shows you a number. It has nothing to do with where the logic is. Just because the page does not refresh, it does not mean to request was not made. So somewhere in the internals, SO receives an ajax request to say "Hey, these notifications were read". The response is probably some JS, JSON, or even just a callback that removes the red notification. With or without JS, the code remains the same. It's up to you how you want to call it.

Comment: Ok, I moved it out the index action. But, like stackoverflow's, I don't want it to redirect but just update the booleans

Comment: Then you need to use Ajax. So take a look at my updated answer. And whether you like it or not, you need to do a redirect if JS is disabled. You can't control that. That's on the client side. Unless you don't want to support on-js browsers.

Answer (score 0):

First of all define your method outside index method.

```
def index    
   @books = Book.all  
end 

def update_read_books
    Book.update_all(read: true)
end
```

define route:

```
resources :books do
  put :update_read_books, on: :collection
end
```

Then in your view:

```
= form_for update_read_books ,:remote => true do |f|
    = f.submit "All Read"
```

Try with this. Hope it will help.

Comment: Oh really, and the controller will just automagically render the JS?

Comment: you don't need to write each and every word for him. He should know about the basics, that he should render a view for it. we are here to help him, not make him copy your code.Understood..?

Comment: What you wrote will cause another error and confuse him even more. The point is to help him understand. This is why I've explained to him what needs to be done and how. Instead, you decided to copy my answer, update it by making it wrong or incomplete.

Comment: I understood at first, what he wants..Not like you editing your post in every 15 seconds...and commenting in every 30 seconds.